# Text displaying on top of img in dropdown with input in IE8

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, html-select

I have an input before dropdown that acts as UI for dropdown

```
<input type="text" value="" name=" " class="txtfield">
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddAMT" SkinID="Form" DataSourceID="LDSAMT" DataTextField="xyz" DataValueField="ABC" Width="220px" CssClass="dd" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="index">
</asp:DropDownList>

.txtfield{
background: url("img.png") no-repeat scroll 98% center #fff;
position: absolute;
width: 175px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding-right:26px;
overflow:hidden;}

.dd{
background-position: left center;
height: 32px;
opacity: 0;    
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
padding-left: 5px;
text-align: left;
width: 209px;
position : relative;
z-index : 10;
display:inline-block;}
```

My issue is that in IE8, if the dropdown option text is more, then textbox that will display text goes on top of image till complete width, it should not happen as padding-right is given to input. It works fine in FF,Chrome i.e it hides text before img.png

Comment: Please show your ACTUAL HTML, not your server-side .NET source code.

Comment: <input class="txtfield" type="text" name=" " value="" style="width: 169px;" readonly="readonly">
<select id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ChildPlaceHolder2_ddCol" class="dd" style="width:200px;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ChildPlaceHolder2$ddCol\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ChildPlaceHolder2$ddCol">